# CentOS 7 install Openvpn failed

Tags: openvpn, centos7

My Centos version is 7.2.1511 ,Kernel 3.10.0-327.22.2.el7.x86_64
Accroding to the link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-centos-7  ,I have installed Openvpn 2.1.3 on my CentOS 7,however it doesn't work.

the error was

```
 [root@localhost centos7]# systemctl status -l openvpn@server.service

    openvpn@server.service - OpenVPN Robust And Highly Flexible Tunneling Application On server
       Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2016-07-23 09:37:42 EDT; 26s ago
      Process: 2076 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon --writepid /var/run/openvpn/%i.pid --cd /etc/openvpn/ --config %i.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

    Jul 23 09:37:42 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN Robust And Highly Flexible Tunneling Application On server...
    Jul 23 09:37:42 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
    Jul 23 09:37:42 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN Robust And Highly Flexible Tunneling Application On server.
    Jul 23 09:37:42 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit openvpn@server.service entered failed state.
    Jul 23 09:37:42 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service failed.
```

I don't like the default port which is 1194,I have change the port to 3000 
and It's not be able to telnet the 3000 
even I tried to start openvpn mannually,it seems doesn't work.

```
[root@localhost centos7]# openvpn /etc/openvpn/server.conf

[root@localhost centos7]# telnet localhost 3000 

Trying ::1...

telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused

Trying 127.0.0.1...

telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

my server.conf was

```
port 3000
#proto tcp
proto udp
dev tun
server 10.8.1.0 255.255.255.0
keepalive 20 120
ca /etc/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/keys/server.crt
key /etc/keys/server.key
dh /etc/keys/dh1024.pem
#crl-verify keys/crl.pem
tls-auth /etc/keys/ta.key 0 
cipher RC2-CBC
user nobody
group nobody
status openvpn-status.log
log-append openvpn.log
verb 2
mute 20
max-clients 200
#management 127.0.0.1 1199
#client-config-dir ccd
client-to-client
persist-key
persist-tun
#ccd-exclusive
#script-security 3 system
push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"
push "redirect-gateway def1"
#push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
#push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.6.6"
#status openvpn-status.log

comp-lzo
verb 3
daemon openvpn
```

My steps of Installation were

```
#1
yum install epel-release
#2
yum install openvpn easy-rsa -y
#3
cp /usr/share/doc/openvpn-*/sample/sample-config-files/server.conf /etc/openvpn
#4
vi /etc/openvpn/server.conf
#5
mkdir -p /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys
#6
I copied the keys which was builded by my old server
#7
yum install iptables-services -y

#8
systemctl mask firewalld
#9
systemctl disable firewalld

#10
systemctl enable iptables
#11
systemctl stop firewalld
#12
systemctl start iptables
#13
iptables --flush
#14 
yum remove firewalld
#15
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
#16
iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
#17
vi /etc/sysctl.conf
#18 Add the following line at the top of the file:
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

what wrong I have done?any idea?

Comment: Changing a default port number also requires changing the SELinux policy for that service which is [well documented](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Managing_Confined_Services/sect-Managing_Confined_Services-Configuration_examples-Changing_port_numbers.html)

Comment: however I have disabled SElinux,but the errors are still remained

Comment: What are saying the openvpn logs ?

Comment: please see this link http://pastebin.com/PX3LirvG    although it sounds like fine in openvpn logs,however I still not be able to telnet the port which is 3000

Comment: What says `netstat -anp | grep 3000` ? Also did you load your sysctl changes : `sysctl -p` ?

Comment: because netstat command doesn't exists in CentOS 7 ,then I yum install net-tools,netstat -anp | grep 3000 return nothing

Comment: hi guys I have resolved the problem.  the tutorial doesn't work at all! all I need to do is to download openvpn source files and confiugre && make && make install,then the openvpn works.